# Google donut chart labeled legend as html not string

Tags: jquery, google-visualization, legend, pie-chart

Can I add custom html for legends of google chart? I want to add additional info and Icon for each part, not only text.

I've added this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6zmbLvk/9/) example

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Source', 'Amount given'],
      ['organic',     50],
        ['direct', 30],
        ['referral', 15],
        ['paid', 5]
    ]);

    var options = {
      pieHole: 0.6,
      legend: 'labeled',
      pieSliceTextStyle: {
        color: '#fff',
      },

        pieSliceText: 'percentage',
        slices: {0: {color: '#27ae60'},
                 1:{color:'#2980b9'},
                 2:{color:'#57C0E8'},
                 3: {color: 'bdc3c7'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donut_single'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: there are no standard [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options) for HTML legends

Comment: So what is the alternative If you know @WhiteHat

Comment: create your own legend or try modifying the SVG on the chart's `'ready'` event...

Comment: @user3003810 as was suggested, your best bet is to create a `<div>` and use CSS to put it into position over the `<svg>`. This is how the floating values are created when you pass over a section or click on a section.

Comment: I found this useful library with the ability to customize legends http://c3js.org/examples.html